# Can I write mkdocs-material docs in HTML?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I use mkdocs-material and want to author the whole documentation in HTML. So basically instead of using Markdown

```
# Title

Paragraph

## Subtitle

Another paragraph
```

I want to  write the same semantic with basic HTML tags:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<p>Paragraph</p>

<h2>Subtitle</h2>

<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

Then I'm going to run `mkdocs build` to apply styles, generate ToC, etc. I've heard it is possible to change the input format in mkdocs, but can't find anything like that in the documentation.

It is possible to insert HTML right in the .md file, but it's not exactly what I want, since ToC is not being generated from `<h1>`, `<h2>` this way.

Answer (score 0):

> it is possible to change the input format in mkdocs

This is probably not true. At least I couldn't find anything like that in the [catalog](https://github.com/mkdocs/catalog).

There are good news tho — we *can* use HTML-formatted text blocks inside Markdown in mkdocs. For instance, it is possible to [add image captions](https://www.markdownguide.org/hacks/#image-captions) with the `<figure>` tag.

HTML headings won't be indexed though — ToC is being generated base on the Markdown headings only. Also, it is impossible to use Markdown inside HTML elements, like this: `<p>*this won't be italic*</p>`.

Comment: many tags _can_ contain markdown, for that, they need to have a `markdown` attribute. Try this: `<p markdown>this **should** render *nicely*.</p>`